# Plot regression lines with interaction in R

Tags: r, regression, curve, interaction

I'm trying to get a scatterplot graph showing 2 regression lines so that interaction effects are clear.
My code is as follows:

```
lm <- lm(Cage_Int ~ Sex + AVP_mvBNST_ros_caud + Sex:AVP_mvBNST_ros_caud, data=data)

plot(data$Cage_Int, data$AVP_mvBNST_ros_caud, xlab="V1aR in BNSTmv", 
     ylab="Interaction time", col=colors, pch=20)
curve(cbind(x,1,x,1*x) %*% coef(lm), add=TRUE, col="red")
curve(cbind(1,0,x,0*x) %*% coef(lm), add=TRUE, col="blue")
```

this gives me the right scatterplot graph,but the regression lines are not showing, which is not what I want (I want both regression lines to show, one for sex=0 and one for sex=1)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Just a friendly note: on SO we have a norm of providing minimal working example (both code & data) so that others can help you. (I didn't down vote, but that was probably the reason.) Also no need for "Thanks!", etc.

Answer (score 0):

Run the regression with `sex=0` and `sex=1` and create two separate linear models using `lm()`. Once you define the two models `model1 = lm(<insert equation>)` and `model2 = lm(<insert second equaiton>)`, you can simply add a line using `abline()` or, in this case:

`abline(model1)
 abline(model2)`

after the plot function and that should do the trick. You can add colors and different line effects using `abline()` as well.